# Trying to add a list of suppliers in an array and then i am adding it to listbox and combobox using `.addrange` but i am receiving error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I retrieved list of suppliers from database and saved it in an array `TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY` NOW i am trying it to add in the listbox or combobox but it shows an error on runtime saying "VALUE CAN NOT BE NULL" but if i try to add it with an loop it works properly why is it not working with `.addrange` ?

```
 Sub GET_SUPPLIERS_DETAILS()

    Dim CON As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; username=root; password=Masoom1; database=airtech_db;")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * from `Suppliers`;", CON)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from `Suppliers`;", CON)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim TOTAL_SUPPLIERS As Integer

    CON.Open()
    da.Fill(ds)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    TOTAL_SUPPLIERS = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    Dim TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS) As String, ARRAYINDEX As Integer
    Do While dr.Read() = True
        TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(ARRAYINDEX) = dr("Supplier_Name").ToString()
        ARRAYINDEX += 1
    Loop
    CON.Close()
    Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        cbCell = DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("Supplier_Name")
        For iIndex = 0 To UBound(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY) - 1
            cbCell.Items.Add(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(iIndex))
        Next
    Next


    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY)
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY)

    For I As Integer = 0 To UBound(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY) - 1
        TextBox1.Text += TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(I) & " - "
    Next I

End Sub
```

This part works only as i added it through a loop

```
For I As Integer = 0 To UBound(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY) - 1
   TextBox1.Text += TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(I) & " - "
Next I
```

`listbox.addrange` command and `combobox.addrange` command not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an issue `TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS)`. Array declared in VB - `array(upper-bound)`. Upper bound is 1 less than count. So, you should do `TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS - 1)`.

But why struggle? Just use list

```
Dim myList as New List(of String) 
While dr.Read()
    myList.Add(dr("Supplier_Name").ToString())
Loop
```

And then, if you still need array, you can use LINQ - `myList.ToArray`

```
ListBox1.DataSource = myList.ToArray()
```